# how to choose the value of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ limit comparison test

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

Let say I need to determine whether the following function diverges or converges.$\frac{2}{n^3-4}$ Do I find the $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{2}{n^3-4}}{\frac{1}{n^3}}$ or  $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n^3}}{\frac{2}{n^3-4}}$.

The example used above is taken from the [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xesQnFWw8f8)
According to the tutorial video, the first method is used however, no clear explanation has been made regrading the chosen method. Can you please explain why the first one works not the second one

Comment: It doesn't matter - the answer will always be > 0 and finite in both if it converges or it will diverge for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you set up the limit, so long as $a_n \geq 0$ and $b_n>0$ then the limit comparison test is conclusive If:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=c$$

And $c$ is positive.

The condition that $b_n>0$ ensures that we do not divide by zero. However, if $a_n>0$ we might as well compute:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_{n}}$$

As if if the previous limit was a positive $c$, now it will be a positive $\frac{1}{c}$. It would be weird if the limit comparison test discriminated against sequences, it really can't tell the difference between $a_n$ and $b_n$. They are what you choose them to be, so long as they follow the conditions of the test.